# Models from blockbench are importing to godot with incorrect textures

Tags: import, textures, godot

I'm importing models from blockbench to godot and the textures work find on the first model but the second model just uses the textures from the first either order i import them in, is there a way to stop this or how can i apply textures to a group of meshes to fix this

replacing the textures individually doesn't work
importing in a different format doesn't work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, the issue was the textures always had the same name and therefore couldn't be imported as another texture with the same name existed so it just used that one, I renamed the texture and it worked